# Distribution of test version of a Windows Phone Application

Tags: windows-phone-7

To be clear, right now, the only possible way to distribute "beta" versions of your app, is to add the device manually (max 3 devices), and install the app via Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right in that there is no way to distribute apps other than sending the XAP file to the person who you want to have the app.

This can then be loaded on to any developer unlocked phone. - Each account can unlock up to 3 devices. (Your appp isn't limited on being loaded onto a maximum of 3 unlocked devices though.)

Your XAP file can be loaded via the "Application Deployment" application which comes with the "Windows Phone Developer Tools" you don't need to use VS.

Microsoft have said that there will be beta distribution available in the future but no details have been released yet.

Answer (score 0):

Updated info on this one:
[Beta testing your app and in-app products](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj215598%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)